# Error : $digest already in progress when using two Http request calls in same angular Js function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm aware of $digest already in progress error issue, but here i'am not calling the apply or digest method explicitly

I'm using two http calls in same angularJS function which leads me to the Error that $digest already in progress, My code is like

```
 $http.post('/CRUDOper/memberInsert',$scope.memberAdd).
        success(function(post){
            if(!post.IsSuccess){
                alert(post.msg + "Try Again");
                return;
            }
            alert("Member Added Successfully");
        }
    );

    var autopass = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
    var passwordinsert = {formno : $scope.memberAdd.formno, password : autopass  };
    $http.post('/CRUDOper/autogeneratepassword',passwordinsert).
        success(function(post){
            if(!post.IsSuccess){
                alert(post.msg + "Try Again");
                return;
            }
            alert("Autogenerated Password for present user : " + autopass );
        }
    );
```

both the request are called correctly what my concern is the error in the firebug that $digest already in progress is there any way i can handle this error ?

Comment: As you mentioned in the question, you shouldn't be getting this problem if you're not calling $apply() or $digest() manually. Are you absolutely sure this is the code snippet causing the issue?

Comment: yes because when i call just one Http request all seem to work fine for me just when i call these two together the problem occurs

Comment: Did you tried to replace alert to console.log?

Comment: Can you specify which lines you commented to test with one AJAX request?

Comment: seems strange but when i removed the alert and kept console as per  Valentyn Shybanov advice it worked but i'm not getting what was the issue with alert then ? the reason i'm asking because when just one http request was called using alert it worked perfectly but the issue began when i called one after another

Comment: I seem to remember some weird bug with Math.random, but don't remember where I saw it...

Comment: As a workaround for now, I guess you might be able to wrap the second post call inside the success of the first one or visa/versa?...

And then file a bug with angular, because there is a way to check if a digest phase is in progress, but that is useless to you here as far as I can tell...

Comment: yes i have tried it already when i call the second http call wrapping inside the the success method of first one it works fine. But..... still not clear with the prior issue

Comment: The issue is that javascript is single threaded. Your second http request is triggered before the first has completed. It works fine when you place it in the callback because the execution thread is free.

Comment: @vipulsharma But it seem to work fine when i remove alert and put console.log , is it because alert is going to block and while console.log won't ? please correct me if i' wrong

Comment: yes you are right. alert blocks the further execution

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS' event loop does not wait until `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()` return a value (at least for `$http` calls). There is, however, a short interval between rendering the popup and entering into the `$digest` loop. This explains why OP did not get the error the first time: OP clicked or pressed return very soon.

To verify for yourself that this does not depend on the number of http calls, try using one alert in the `success()` method of a single http call. There will be no error if you confirm the popup within approx. 300ms, but there will be an error if you confirm it at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $window.alert instead.
Still this happens when another digest is in progress, a quick workaround is wrap it into a $timeout()